# CMS Element config not saved correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, shopware6

A custom **CMS element** I have created in **Shopware 6.4.20.1** is apparently not saving various properties correctly in the `element.config` object.

You can edit elements in two different places:

1. The WYSIWYG editor.
2. From the "Layout" tab in Shopware's "category" administration.

When initially creating the element inside the WYSIWYG editor, everything saves correctly, and I can also return later and update the various properties.

But, as soon as the element settings are changed *one time* from the "category layout tab", I can no longer use the editor. The layout tab sort of "takes over the control" of the specific element, and I will no longer be able to edit the same element from the WYSIWYG. However, other elements edit just fine on the same page.

Also, changes from the category tab are not reflected in the editor, but they *will* show up in the storefront.

If I try to edit from the editor anyway, the changes will be saved, and even loaded again inside the editor, but it seems to now work independently from the category tab settings, and the changes from the editor also will not show up in the storefront.

Keep in mind, editing from the category layout tab works fine to update the element in the storefront.

**How the config data is changed**

I have used `v-model="element.config.value.propertyName"` on all input fields.

What could the cause for this be? Should Shopware not automatically make sure the config object is saved with the associated CMS element, regardless of where you edit from?